# Connect to internet through two gateways

Tags: networking, nat, gateway

I am developing a library to perform port forwarding in NAT devices. Using SSDP (de discovery process) I can see two different UPnP servers that implement WANIPConnection service type, one is my ADSL modem and the other is my Windows Server.

My LAN joins to internet through the ADSL modem so, I know which server I have to use. However, is it possible for one computer connect to internet through two different gateways?

**Update**:

By gateway I mean any device that allow access to internet. For example, just imagine you have two ADSL modems at home, each of those gives access using two different ISPs. And you have only one PC connected by a wire to ADSL modem 1 and by WiFi to ADSL modem 2.

```
ISP 1 -----------> ADSL 1 ----\
                               \
                                +-> PC
                               /
ISP 2 -----------> ADSL 2 ----/
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "gateway"? Do you mean a router? A router on the local LAN? A UPnP server visible to a client machine"? Or something else?

Comment: Next question would be what kind of OS you're using?  From the buzzwords used, I'd guess it's a Windows, but I'm not really sure so please provide a bit more information.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've updated my question. Gateway in this context is a router or an adsl modem that supports UPnp to manage ports.

Comment: @AndreasWiese NAT, SSDP, UPnP, WANIPConnection, ADSL, ISP, WiFi and PC are not buzzwords at all and they have nothing to do with Windows, Linux, Mac, etc.
Yes, gateway is an old-fashioned word, I admit it.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't that religiously charged as it might be understood.  WANIPconnection didn't sound like something standards defined.  Mea culpa.  Intend of the question only was »Which OS?«, and this is still open.

Comment: @AndreasWiese I am using a laptop with Windows 8, another one with Ubuntu 12.04, a NAS server running Ubuntu Server 12.04 and my ADSL modem runs a tiny linux (it seems to be a custom distro).

Answer (score 0):

For Linux (as long as your ADSL modem has the appropriate tools available), the solution to your problem would be rather easy to accomplish.  You'd have to setup multiple routes with the same *metric*.  With such a setup, connections would be (hopefully) evenly distributed along all available routes:

```
# ip route add default via <1st-gateway> metric 1024
# ip route add default via <2nd-gateway> metric 1024
```

The metric's value is purely fictional (this would be important if you have routes with different cost, e.g. UMTS vs. cable connection — lower numbers meaning higher priority [resp. lower cost]).  This would tell the kernel to »evenly« distribute traffic above both gateways.  Note that routing decisions are cached by the kernel, thus if 90% of your traffic goes to, e.g., <s>`facebook.com`</s> `superuser.com` it would mean that 90% of your traffic goes through *one* gateway.

Analogous steps would be required for Windows, but I'm not really firm at doing routing with Windows (but you might get the point).

Comment: Can't seem to have multiple routes with "same" metric. Different metric, yes, but only one would ever be used.
`RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

What load-balancing mechanism were you trying to refer to?